# I want to create a custom DropdownButton in flutter which can be reusable, here the hint name and list will be different for all DropdownButton

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dropdownbutton

Here I am getting an error in Hint, when I pass HintName in hint it throws an error, as well I would like to know how can I call a particular list in parameter for example if I want to call the custom DropDownButton with MDPackageType list and hint 'Package Type' how we can implement this.

This is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  final String HintName;
  final List<String> MDPT;

  CustomDropDown(this.HintName, this.MDPT);
  @override
  _CustomDropDownState createState() => _CustomDropDownState();
}

class _CustomDropDownState extends State<CustomDropDown> {
  String? dropdownvalue;
  var MDPackageType = [
    'Package Type 1',
    'Package Type 2',
    'Package Type 3',
    'Package Type 4',
  ];
  var MDPackageName = [
    'Package Name 1',
    'Package Name 2',
    'Package Name 3',
    'Package Name 4',
  ];

  var PTPackageType = [
    'Package Type 1',
    'Package Type 2',
    'Package Type 3',
    'Package Type 4',
  ];
  var PTPackageName = [
    'Package Type 1',
    'Package Type 2',
    'Package Type 3',
    'Package Type 4',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FormField<String>(
      builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
        return InputDecorator(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            // labelStyle: textStyle,

            // errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 16.0),
            hintText: 'Package Type',
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
            ),
          ),
          isEmpty: dropdownvalue == '',
          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
              hint: const Text(
                HintName,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
              ),
              value: dropdownvalue,
              isDense: true,
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownvalue = newValue;
                  state.didChange(newValue);
                });
              },
              items: MDPT.map((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(
                    value,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }


[![My expected output][1]][1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the error message you're getting? One possible issue is that you have const in hint property, try removing that first. Also, u can try widget.Hintname, instead of Hintname

Comment: it worked for hint by removing cont, changing to widget.HintName and making it has required. same way how we can call a list through a parameter, as i have 4 list and every dropdown has different list, can we do it by re using the class